# IE 7.0 Select box overlap over button

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer

My google skills are falling me.
I'm having the following issue in IE 7.0 (works in FF 4.0 & Chrome)

I initially have an empty select box.  When I fill it values using Jquery, the select box is overlapping over the button.

I'm assuming there's a css hack for it but I'm not getting the proper search results.

I have the following bit of code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <select id="missionList" name="missionList">
            <option></option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
        </select>
        <select name="peopleList" id="slPeopleFoundList" size="5" multiple="multiple">
        </select>
        <input type="submit" id="Remove" value="Remove" disabled="disabled" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {

        $("#missionList").change(function () {
            SetupUpMissionList();
        });

        function SetupUpMissionList() {
            var select = $("#slPeopleFoundList");

            appendOption("he asdfasdfasdf asdf asdf asdfllo", "hello", select);
        }

        function appendOption(text, value, select) {
            $(select).
                  append($("<option></option>").
                  attr("value", value).
                  text(text));
        }

    });

</script>
```

Comment: I can't seem to replicate your problem. http://jsfiddle.net/dj92U/1/

Comment: Hey Shrubery, open up your link in IE 7.0 and you should see the problem.  Great site by the way, I'll have to play around with it..

Comment: Yeah sorry, misunderstood the problem, I see it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stupid, stupid IE.  I tried adding .hide()/.show() around the code that adds options to the select element and it kind of worked, like so:

```
select.hide();
appendOption("he asdfasdfasdf asdf asdf asdfllo", "hello", select);
select.show();
```

Comment: This also seemed to work after adding an item to the select list: `/* if IE version <=7 then */ $(select).css({width: "auto"})` -- [see demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/kkSPa/11/)

Comment: Adding the `width: auto` to the css is probably the better solution of the 2.

Comment: Very nice, I think I like the second suggestion better. It's interesting that it likes the width tag with jquery but if you put it in the html directly, the same problem occurs.  Too bad I can't upvote you twice (unless you can post another answer).